# Sources for the birth of Elizabeth Shaw Whaley in Connecticut c.1813?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, birth-records, connecticut

I have undocumented family genealogy records that Elizabeth Shaw Whaley:

- was born 6 Feb 1813 in Montville, Connecticut to  William Patten Whaley and Philena Haughton
- married Elijah Genubeth Strong (1818 - 1865) on 22 Nov 1843 in Uncasville, Connecticut
- was still living (a widow) in 1870 census

I am looking for sources/citations for her birth (date, place, parents).

I have googled her and found hits on werelate.org, ancestry.com, and geni.com among others. Ancestry in particular had quite a large number of personal sites with the above information but I was not able to find any sources when looking through them.

I have searched for her on americanancestors.org (the NEHGS site) but was unsuccessful in finding anything.

I searched on myheritage.com and found others with similar information, but not sources.

Where can I find sources for her birth?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [History of Montville, Connecticut, formerly the North parish of New London from 1640 to 1896](http://archive.org/details/historyofmontvil00bake) has the information you seek, courtesy of the Internet Archive:

> III. WILLIAM P. (20), b. 27 NW., 1786, son of Jona- 
>   than Whaley and Mercy Chester; married 29 Sept., 1811, 
>   Philena Haughton... He died 22 Feb., 1851. 
>   She died 22 May, 1851.
>
> Children.
>
> 25 Elizabeth Shaw, b. 4 Feb., 1813; in. Elijah Strong, 22
>   Nov., 1843. She died 22 Nov., 1870.

I don't know what sources were used to compile the information in the book.

Comment: Thank you. Did you specifically search archive.org (I hadn't) or did you find with internet search? If the latter, I'm curious what search terms you used (since yours obviously worked better than mine). I know search engines individualize results (and you likely do many more genealogy searches than I do) so might be I couldn't have done anything differently. But if I could, I'd like to know.

Comment: @Duncan I used Google. I believe I searched for Philena Haughton after a search for Elizabeth Whaley and William Whaley came up short.

Answer (score 2):

One likely place to start is [The Barbour Collection of Connecticut Town Vital Records:
Madison 1826-1805, Manchester 1823-1853, Marlborough 1803-1852, Meriden 1806-1853, Middlebury 1807-1850, Monroe 1823-1854, Montville 1786-1850, Volumes 27-28](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_Barbour_Collection_of_Connecticut_To.html?id=pTAoAQAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y)

Various sites have transcriptions of the Barbour collection for different places, so you may be able to find them online if you look.

[FamilySearch Wiki](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Barbour_Collection) suggsts the old IGI or Ancestry may be of use.